# Google's oauth2client.getToken() incorrectly returns when called with Q.ninvoke()

Tags: node.js, q, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client, google-api-js-client

I'm using Google's node.js library to retrieve access tokens to authenticate a user. If I call the following method using a node-style callback, returned `tokens` is an object as I see in official examples:

```
oauth2client.getToken(code, function(err, tokens) {
    console.log(tokens.access_token);
    console.log(tokens.refresh_token);
});
```

When I wrap it in `Q.ninvoke` (in my app I'm trying to use promises everywhere, for self-teaching reasons), I get an array instead: the first element is the `tokens` object, the second is an object of type `IncomingMessage`:

```
Q.ninvoke(oauth2client, "getToken", code).then(function(tokens) {
    // Here tokens is:
    //
    // [ { access_token: 'XXXXXXX',
    //     token_type: 'Bearer',
    //     refresh_token: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    //     expiry_date: 1452516187132 },
    //   IncomingMessage {
    //     _readableState: 
    //      ReadableState {
    //        objectMode: false,
    //        highWaterMark: 16384,
    //        buffer: [],
    //        length: 0,
    //        pipes: null,
    //        pipesCount: 0,
    //        flowing: ... ... ... ... etc
});
```

**Why? What am I missing?** I tried wrapping standard node functions in `Q.ninvoke`, and the result is as expected, so I think it can be something with the Google library, and not related to Q, idk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oauth2client.getToken()` apparently calls its callback with more than two arguments, in which case Q will gather all arguments (the ones after `err`) into an array that gets passed to the `.then()` callback (which only takes one argument).

You can use `.spread()` to spread these out into separate arguments again (and since you're only interested in the first, you can ignore the rest):

```
Q.ninvoke(oauth2client, "getToken", code).spread(function(tokens) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Great, it worked and I understood what was causing the issue. Thank you!